# Some javascript code prevents form submit

Tags: javascript, debugging

I am developing plugin for one store and by some reason when I enable my plugin form doesn't submits. I checked console and and no errors or some messages, nothing cover it because button reflecting on press. As well as js load is a huge, I can't imagine how can I debug it and find the reason of this failure. Is there a way to start debug when I press submit button?

Answer (score 0):

Check for preventDefault or stopPropagation / stopImmediatePropagation call, into plugin !